# Laurent Series of $f(z) = \frac{1}{e^z - 1}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, laurent-series

The Laurent Series of $f(z)$ centred at $0$ can be written as,

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{z}{12} - \frac{z^3}{720} + \cdots$$

So we see that $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $0$. Can we conclude that the ring of convergence of the Laurent Series is the exterior of the unit disk $|z|\geq 1$ and if so, what is the radius of convergence?

Comment: How did you calculate such Laurent expansion? What is the expression of the general $n$-th term?

Comment: As described in [this site](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/use-division-to-obtain-the-laurent-series-representation-1ez-1-1z-12-112z-1720z3-0-z-2/#), everything goes clear until I do not understand how do you distribute
$$\frac{1}{z}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty
 (-1)^k
 \left(
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}
 \right)^k$$
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it converges on $\{0<|z|<2\pi\}$, since the next pole occurs at $e^{\pm 2\pi i}$.

Comment: Does that mean that there are a number of Laurent Series valid in annuli between the poles?

Comment: There's one for each annulus, yes.

Comment: Oh, cool. I'm looking to construct a function whose ring of convergence is the exterior of the unit disk. I think that I have just found one: $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}$

Comment: Yes, that'll work fine.

Comment: Why does this work fine?

Comment: @user24907: Because the geometric series $\sum (1/z)^n$ converges for $|1/z|<1$.

Comment: which is equivalent to |z|>1? I think I see it now. Thank you.

Comment: What is the corresponding Laurent series expansion centered at $z=2\pi i$?

Comment: @DrPotato What do you think?

Comment: Your answer on the convergence radius is indeed correct, but I have not seen anywhere the explicit expression of the $n$-th coefficient of such Laurent series centered at $z=0$,as I commented above yesterday. The series centered at $2\pi i$ could be easily obtained through first removing that pole.

Comment: @DrPotato  I have no idea what you’re talking about. The coefficients are *Bernoulli numbers*. And by periodicity you obtain the Laurent series at $2\pi i$ by substituting $z-2\pi i$ for $z$ in the original Laurent series.

Comment: @TedShifrin When I wrote "I have not seen anywhere the explicit expression of the $n$-th coefficient of such Laurent series centered at $z=0$," I mean: What is the $n$-th coefficient? no one has explained how to simplify it! They only write "$1/z-1/2+z/12-z/750+ \dots$" All I could get from this thread so far for the Laurent series centered at $0$ is 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z}{(n+1)!} \right)^k$$
as I posted in another comment (please look above, there is a link)