# Laurent series of $1/(exp(1/x)-1)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, laurent-series

I have been struggling to find the Laurent series of 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^{1/z}-1}$$
and its convergence radius as well. Please help me!

It seems to have an essential discontinuity at $z=0$ and $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ some sort of pole at $z=\frac{1}{2\pi i k }$.

Thank you very much expert texperts!

Comment: In the neighborhood of which point do you need to expand in the Laurent series?

Comment: This doesn't have a pole at $z=1$, it is normally defined there.

Comment: In fact, $0$ is not an isolated singular point here (this is the limit point of the poles $\frac{1}{2\pi k i}$), therefore, it is impossible to expand Laurent series in a neighborhood of zero. But you can expand it in neighborhood of infinity or any pole.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I just corrected! I meant $i$.

Comment: @thing Nice! Thank you! Therefore this question is related to
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/778897/622884
 with the change of variable $w=1/z$.

Comment: Now please tell me: as described in [this site](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/use-division-to-obtain-the-laurent-series-representation-1ez-1-1z-12-112z-1720z3-0-z-2/#), everything goes clear until I do not understand how do you distribute
$$\frac{1}{z}
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty
 (-1)^k
 \left(
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}
 \right)^k$$
any ideas? I mean: How to calculat the $n$-th coefficient precisely?

Comment: @DrPotato, So, you never said at what point you want the expansion.

Comment: To get a decomposition that you don’t understand, simply use the formula $\frac{1}{1+w}=\sum(-1)^kw^k$, where $|w|<1$ and $w=\sum\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: @thing Oh! Late response: I need to expand its Laurent series in the neighborhood of $z=2\pi i$.

Comment: @DrPotato, But it's not singularity and Laurent series equals to Taylor series. Maybe you mean $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$?

Comment: ohh!! yeah, sorry, sure, that's what I mean!
(actually I am working with the change of variable $w=1/z$ that is why I invert things in this question)

Comment: @DrPotato, are you sure that you need the whole Laurent series, and not some coefficient, say, $c_{-1}$? Write out the whole series will not work, because there is a triple infinite sum, and two of them is raised to a power. The radius of convergence of any Laurent series will be $1$.